# Retrieve information from all the URLs in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below that uses xml.
It visits all the URLs in column J, gets information, then pastes it to column K.

The code does not seem to work.

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sdd As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim url As Range

    For Each url In Range("J2:J" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow

            With Http
                .Open "GET", url, False
                .send
                Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With
            sdd = Html.querySelector("span[itemprop='price']").getAttribute("content")
            Sheet1.Cells(i, "K") = sdd
        Next i
    Next
    End
End Sub
```

The macro is now able to run. I don't why its running all of a sudden.
But its still not doing what it is supposed to.
If there are 10 URLs in column J, the macro will get the info from the first URL, then put it on all rows in column K instead of just putting it on its respective row. If the value from the first URL is 80000, it would put 80000 on all 10 rows. Not only that, it would move on to the next URL, then put the new info on all of the rows in column K by replacing what it had just put there. It would do that until it has gone all the way through the 10th URL.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided in your question. It would help if you include the documents (or, preferably, the URL's) you are using from column J.

Comment: Hi Ron, its www.realtor.com

Comment: OK, explain what *does not seem to work* means?  Error? Crash? something else?

Comment: It actually behaves differently. First it does not work at all, its either saying that the `.send` is the source of error. Then sometimes its the `Next` thats giving the error. Then just recently, after I restarted my computer, its able to run the macro but its pasting the result of the first URL on all the rows with entries on column K, then replace it with the result of the second URL on all the rows with entries on column K, then replace it with the result of the third URL and so on until it has gone through all the URLs on column J.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Its not giving the error anymore. It is able to run the macro, but its pasting the information that I want in all of the rows in column K. So like if there are 10 URLs on the list in column J, the macro will get the info from the first URL, paste it on all 10 rows instead of just pasting it on the 2nd row (1st row is header) where it took the information from. It would then continue by pasting the information it got from the second URL on the list then replace the ones it just pasted on all the 10 rows. It would continue to do that until it reached the 10th URL.

Comment: Im actually glad that you are looking into this. The URLs are working because they are to get the information. The URL is www.realtor.com, then an address is on column A, the addresses can be anything. There's a formula on column J where it would concatenate the URL and the address so that it would lead to the intended URL. Im not hesitating to supply the data, its just that its dynamic.

Comment: If this would really help, here's a random address on cell J2, https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/8500-Wyndstar-Pl_Louisville_KY_40242_M34319-52785 then on cell J3 https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/232-Sage-Rd_Louisville_KY_40207_M41695-74032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not indexing into the `K` column properly.  You have a `For I` loop which repeats for every URL.  So the last URL will fill all of the `K` column entries.  Perhaps something like:

```
…
    i = 1
    Columns("K").Clear
    For Each URL In Range(Cells(2, "J"), Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        sdd = HTML.querySelector("span[itemprop='price']").getAttribute("content")
        i = i + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, "K") = sdd

    Next URL
End Sub
```

Oh, and ensure that your URL's are fully formed:  eg  that they start with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Wow amazing! It really does the job.  I didnt realize I was just missing a few lines. Thanks Ron, I truly appreciate it. Neatly done! Props to you.
 Now I will just figure out if I should make this as a private sub wherein after a new set of addresses are put into column J, it would run this function automatically or keep it as is. Is it normal that while it is fetching the information from the different websites, I cant type or do anything until it finishes? My concern is what if I have thousands of URLs.

Comment: @SoaringRioren Only update the new URL's.  To be able to `type or do` something while this is running, set `async` to `True`.  Of course, you'd have to keep checking to see if the call had finished before you can do anything dependent on that call if you did that.

Comment: I see. I suppose I should put an `async = true` before the `For Each url In Range("J2:J" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` then `async = false` after `Next URL`, am I right?

Comment: @SoaringRioren `async` is an argument of the `.Open` method.  And no, your example is wrong.  You'll also need to check if the call has finished before you continue your macro.  I think you need to examine the HELP documentation for the `XML` and `HTTP` methods you are using in order to fully understand this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help Ron, you fixed the problem. `async` shouldnt be that complicated for a newbie like me to handle. Thanks again Ron for fixing the code. I truly appreciate your help.